# Balanced String Recursion Returns Improperly

Tags: python, string, recursion, return

I'm currently working on a problem to write a recursive program to remove all the balanced bracket operators from a string or return False if the string is not balanced. I can get the program to remove all the brackets but, according to the debugger, when the program does its final base case check to verify that the string is empty, the program jumps from return True in line 3 to isBalanced recursive call in line 10. I don't understand why this is happening. Code is the following:

```
def isBalanced(string):
    if not string:          # Base Case. If the string is empty then return True
        return True
    else:
        j = 0
        for i in string:    # Iterate thru the str looking for (), {}. and [] pairs, looking for closed bracket first
            if (i == ')') or (i == ']') or (i == '}'):
                if (i == ')') and (string[j-1] == '('):
                    new_string = string[:j-1] + string[j+1:]        # Remove ()
                    isBalanced(new_string)
                elif (i == ']') and (string[j-1] == '['):
                    new_string = string[:j-1] + string[j+1:]        # Remove []
                    isBalanced(new_string)
                elif (i == '}') and (string[j-1] == '{'):
                    new_string = string[:j-1] + string[j+1:]        # Remove {}
                    isBalanced(new_string)
                else:       # Did not find an open bracket to match a closed bracket operator
                    print('Program failed at:', string)
                    return False
            else:
                j += 1                                          # Index counter


test_str = "({[]()})"
print(isBalanced(test_str))
```

Comment: The debugger is going up the call stack. Calling `return` exits the current recursion level and continues at the previous level.

Comment: It's the other way round; ```isBalanced``` of line 10 calls ```return True``` of line 3

Comment: Okay thanks guys. I replaced at the straight isBalanced() calls with return IsBalanced() and it works.